# How to convert a string array element to string?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

I have a string array

```
public: array<String ^> ^ sss;
public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
        array<String ^> ^ sss = gcnew array<String ^>(3);
        sss[0]="asdasd";
        sss[1]="s115ss";
        sss[2]="s115ss";
    }
```

I need to show the 1st element into a textbox.

I used

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             textBox2->Text = sss[0];
         }
```

Vc++ gave `System.NullReferenceException`. Why? And how to fix it?

The error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in test000.exe
>   Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Please add the full stack trace. Based on the information you've provided I am willing to bet that the NullReference is the object `textbox` not `s`

Comment: Not Right. The following code works in my program textBox2->Text = "11111";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code shouldn't compile, unless you also have a field called `sss`. If that's the case, you want to set the value of that field in your constructor, not of some unrelated local variable with the same name:

```
array<String ^> ^ sss;

public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        sss = gcnew array<String ^>(3);
        sss[0]="asdasd";
        sss[1]="s115ss";
        sss[2]="s115ss";
    }
```

Comment: I am sorry I forget to add that in my post. I have that code in my code (just edited my post), but my program does not work.

Comment: Like I said, you want to set the field, not some local variable in the constructor. Change the line where you `gnew` the array to the one in my answer.

Comment: You are right. I am sorry that I did not catch what you mean at the first time.